# How to don't mix Facebook chatbot with normal conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot, facebook-chat

I'm creating a facebook chatbot to talk in name of my facebook page.

Usually customers talks to my company using this channel.

When I started to use chatbot to ask some stuff to my registered customers I'm getting hundreds of answers and notifications on my messenger page and it is a total mess cause it is mixing survey answers with the normal customer conversations.

What can I do to separate both channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Handover Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol) from Facebook. I think it plays well with default Facebook Page Inbox. However, if you use some 3rd party app for managing your messenger conversation, you should ask your provider how to solve this problem.

When we implement chatbots we see it all around. 3rd party providers are starting to add API endpoints to tell if the bot handed over the conversation and vice versa.